# SqlConnection.Open throwing exception C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Attempting to make a login form in `C#`, connecting to a `SQL server`. But It keeps throwing exceptions at the `cn.Open();`. I am using `XAMPP` for my `SQL Server`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BlackLight_CSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=blacklight_login");
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username= '"+txt_user.Text+"' AND Password = '"+txt_pass.Text+"'", cn);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count += 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
                dashboard dash = new dashboard();
                dash.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password, Try again.");
            }

            txt_user.Clear();
            txt_pass.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are screen shots of the errors,

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: So, what is unclear regarding the message of the exception? Have you checked the server availability? What is your question? And please do not use screenshots in the question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yh2c5mL.png Server is fine. My question is, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: What kind of server you are using? Is it sqlexpress, localdb?

Comment: Isn't the password missing in connection string?

Comment: @Ace XAMPP? you mean u are using MySQL? why the hell you are connecting to MSSQL then?

Comment: For MySql you need MySQL Connector/NET. See MySql official page.

Comment: You also should consider using a parametrized query! Please don't use a string concatenation for your SQL-commands!

Comment: you should change the question because is not clear you are using mySQL and not MSSQL after the people investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Clear that you are using `MySQL` And You are using `SqlClient` which supports `MSSQL` change your database dataprovider to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) and use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`instead.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql server you need 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection instead of SqlConnection.
Check: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL